# Items in an array that contains

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am trying to write a function that would check if the items in the array has the word "game" and return the value.

```
function() {
   var game = [];
   if({{dataLayer - page - gamename}}.toLowerCase().indexOf("game") > -1)
       return game();
}
```

please let me know what am i doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you expect the index of the `"game"` word.`game` is an array with the word.
`var game=["a","b","c","d","Game","e","f"];`
`function find()`
`{`
`for(i=0;i<game.length;i++)`
`{`
`if(game[i].toLowerCase()=="game")`
`return i;`
`break;`
 `}`
`}`

Comment: What is your expectation?I can't understand getting undefined.